# how to select rows from dataset in python

Tags: python

I have a dataset that has a column that accepts only 0 and 1 values (see vegan and vegetarian columns).

[image]

I want to select the records that have the value 1 and create a new dataset containing all other columns in order to create a scatter plot for specific restaurants only.
that's how it looks with all records:

[image]

and this is the code of the plot:

```
fig = px.scatter(df, x='review_score', y='number_of_reviews', color='Vegetarian Options',
                 hover_data=['food_type1','restaurant_name'])
fig.show()
```

Comment: I don't know if correctly I understood question but could you try: dff=df.loc[df['vegan'] == 1]

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to make a new dataframe with only values == 1 and keep only the other columns:

```
import pandas as pd

row1list = [0, 1, 'rest', 'rant']
row2list = [1, 0, 'rest', 'or rant']
row3list = [0, 1, 'rest', 'stop']
df = pd.DataFrame([row1list, row2list, row3list],
                  columns=['Vegan Options', 'Vegetarian Options', 'col_abc', 'col_xyz'])

for col in ['Vegan Options', 'Vegetarian Options']:
    df_filtered = df[df[col] == 1]    # keep only the rows where col value == 1
    del df_filtered[col]              # delete the column you filtered on
```